# Why ReadAsync is faster in FileStream vs StreamReader in C#?

Tags: async-await

I am writing a method to read large files using new ReadAsync methods. In my testing looks like FileStream ReadAsync is faster than StreamReader, not sure why?

### ReadStreamReaderAsync

Thread ID Before Await : 9

Thread ID After Await : 13

**Time : 76626**

Total Bytes : 687184052

### ReadFileStreamAsync

Thread ID Before Await : 9

Thread ID After Await : 10

**Time : 19167**

Total Bytes : 687184052

```
  static async Task<long> ReadStreamReaderAsync(string filename)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread ID Before Await : {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        long totalBytes = 0;
        var sp = new Stopwatch();
        sp.Start();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default))
        {
            char[] buffer = new char[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                totalBytes += numRead;
            }
        }

        sp.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread ID After Await : {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Time : {0}", sp.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        return totalBytes;
    }

    static async Task<long> ReadFileStreamAsync(string filePath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread ID Before Await : {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        long totalBytes = 0;
        var sp = new Stopwatch();
        sp.Start();
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                totalBytes += numRead;
            }          
        }

        sp.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread ID After Await : {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Time : {0}", sp.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        return totalBytes;
    }
```

Comment: What do they do different? Do you think that could account for it?

Answer (score 6):

`StreamReader` is using an encoder to read the data (UTF-8).

If you have used a UTF-8 based file you will potentially have received less data as UTF-8 can encoded to many bytes and the Encoder will understand this.

`FileStream` is dumb and is giving you raw data and trusting you know how to handle it.  So if for instance you are reading a text file you should use `StreamReader` (with the correct encoder)